# Dangerfile Swift Give File Name

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle, swiftlint

I am currently integrating Danger into BuddyBuild so that it runs pre-build and post-build for me.

I have two different Dangerfiles that I want to use.

Buddybuild's website for integrating Danger says to run this line:

`bundle exec danger --fail-on-errors=true`

Is there a way to pass in an argument that gives it the file name also? From what I'm reading, this basically would just find the file called `Dangerfile` and use that to run danger, but I want two different ones, namely `Dangerfile-prebuild` and `Dangerfile-postbuild`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see you're using buddybuild!

You can run `danger --dangerfile=path` to specify the danger-file to use. In buddybuild's context, that means using `bundle exec danger --dangerfile=Dangerfile-prebuild` in a `buddybuild_prebuild.sh` and `bundle exec danger --dangerfile=Dangerfile-postbuild` in a `buddybuild_postbuild.sh`.

Let me know if this helps!